# Reading CSV files in a loop using pandas, then concatenating them

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have 10 csv files, named `data_run1_all.csv`, `data_run2_all.csv`, ..., `data_run10_all.csv`. CSV files have same columns, but different rows.

Now I am importing them one by one to `df_run1`, `df_run2`, ..., `df_run10`.

Can I use a loop to import them? Something like: `i=1 to 10, df_runi=pandas.read_csv('data_runi_all.csv')`.

I am asking because the data analysis, plotting, etc. for each data frame are same, too. All the code for each data frame is repeated 10 times. If I can use a loop to do 10 times, the code will be much shorter and readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read your CSVs in a loop and call `pd.concat`:

```
file_name = 'data_run{}_all.csv'
df_list = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_name.format(i))

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

---

Alternatively, you could build the list inside a comprehension:

```
file_name = 'data_run{}_all.csv'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file_name.format(i)) for i in range(1, 11)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `df_run` a list. You could do something like this:

```
df_run = []
for i in range(1,10):
  df_run.append(pandas.read_csv('data_run{0}_all.csv'.format(i))
for df in df_run:
  // Do your processing
```

Or do everything in a single loop, and avoid having the list.