# Read different .csv files into different dataframes with a loop with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

Please, before marking this question as duplicated read the whole post. I know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502943/reading-csv-files-in-a-loop-using-pandas) post has a similar question but what I'm looking for is somehow different.

I have a list of file names:

```
files = ['first.csv', 'second.csv', 'third.csv']
```

And I want to read them inside a loop with pandas. What I expect is to create for each iteration inside the loop a different dataframe:

```
first = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
second = pd.read_csv('second.csv')
third = pd.read_csv('third.csv')
```

But inside a loop. Something like:

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    csv = re.split('.', files[i])[0]
    csv = pd.read_csv(files[i])
```

**IMPORTANT**: Each csv has different rows and columns. So what I want is not to read the three csv to combine them into one with `pd.concat`. I want to read them separately.

I tried to read them into a list with:

```
dataframe_list = [pd.read_csv(file_name) for file_name in files]
```

But that raises the next error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 59: invalid start byte
```

Comment: "Something like" is exactly what you need (except for the second line, which is useless). Did you try?

Comment: @DYZ, won't what they have simply result in csv being the dataframe corresponding to `third.csv`? It sounds like they want three different dataframes.

Comment: append in the new_list after creating a new df

Comment: Well that link appears to have everything you want. If you want to have all of the `DataFrames` separately, then storing them in the list is an option, or use a dictionary if you want more sensible keys to reference them.

Comment: More efficiently, you can get a list of dataframes with `frames=[pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]` or even `frames=list(map(pd.read_csv, files))`.

Comment: @ALollz please read the edition I made to the post, I think that is not duplicated. I don't want to concat them.

Comment: @DYZ I think I didn't explain the problem well, check the edition. I really think it's not the same issue.

Comment: @Rubén that error is an issue with reading the csv, not storing them in a list. If all of the files have different encodings, you can either specify the encodings for each file in a dictionary, or more haphazardly, use a try and except clause. `except UnicodeDecodeError:` and then try reading the bad files with the added argument `encoding='latin-1'` within `pd.read_csv`

Comment: @Rubén The confusion might be that the linked question is a duplicate of the question you asked, but not the problem that you're having. If ALollz's comment doesn't help, you should ask **new** question focused more specifically on the encoding issue

Comment: @Rubén: a UnicodeDecodeError reading one of the files is a separate issue not covered by this current question, please try to isolate which single file, then treat that as a new separate question (and search for existing answers). As to this current question, yes I don't think it is an exact duplicate so should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
dataframe_list = [pd.read_csv(file_name) for file_name in files]
```

then you can call `dataframe_list[0]` to get the first dataframe, and so on. You might want to use a dictionary instead with keys being the dataframe labels you want.

---

Quick tip: the construct `for i in range(0, len(files))` and then only caring about `files[i]` is ugly. `files` is a list, so you can iterate over it using `for file in files`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried your solution but it raises this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 59: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['first.csv', 'second.csv', 'third.csv']
list_of_df=[]
for i in range(len(files)):
    df = pd.read_csv(files[i],encoding = "utf-8")
    list_of_df.append(df)
```

Comment: I tried but got this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 59: invalid start byte

Comment: you need to pass encoding parameter.