# parse blocky csv in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, parsing, import

I have a tons of .csv's.
They are composed of sub-blocks of .csv different size (columns and rows).
How do I import them in pandas?
e.g:

```
   //// junk
   a,b,c,
   0,1,2,
   //// junk
   d,z,e,f
   0,3,3,3
```

I have tried

```
pd.readcsv (skiprows=..)
```

however, the length  and the presence of the individual blocks is variable.
I know the values of the upper most left cell of the sub-dataframes (e.g. 'a' and 'd').
Is there a simple of way  of dealing with such case?

Comment: what's your goal, split the file above file in two csvs (or dataframe) with different column names? Merge in one single CSV (or dataframe) with columns a,b,c,d,e,f,z

Comment: having the two dataframe separated in two variables

Comment: you could split source file by "///" and than apply a for loop to the list of files https://stackoverflow.com/a/51973637/757714