# Creating with python a vocabulary file that takes the words from a set (a huge set) of .tsv files and for each word assigns an identification number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this set of files .tsv (it's really big, 18k+ files) and i want to create a file (doesn't matter what format it is) called 'vocabulary' that will storage each word that appears in these files and assigns an identifier to each word. I don't want to count occurrences: if the word "house" appears 227 times in my files i want to save that word in my vocabulary just once.
I will use this vocabulary for a search engine, but this is another story...

Edit: I forgot that i also want to name each identifier in a specific way: 'term_id'. So i imagine the content of my output file something like:

```
    house_id_1
    flower_id_2
    river_id_3
    and_id_4
    beautiful_id_5
```

Comment: To read the `.tsv` files use [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502943/reading-csv-files-in-a-loop-using-pandas-then-concatenating-them) and to find the unique features use pandas [series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Windows machine or a Linux/Unix/MacOS machine?

If latter, you don't really need Python - you can do it by chaining together shell commands -

If one of your files is called `abc.txt` -

```
while read p; do printf "%s %s \n" $p `echo $p|md5sum`; done <abc.txt |sort|uniq > outputfile.txt
```

Note that the md5sum hashes the word - almost guarantees a unique ID for each of your words

Comment: I'm using a windows machine and I'm working right now on a Jupyter notebook where i actually splitted a big .csv file in multiple .tsv for future purposes. So i can even take the words from a unique .csv file if it is less time consuming.

Comment: How big is your `csv` file? Can you load the entire file into memory? By using `open("csvfile", "r")` in python, for example?

Comment: Yes I can load it in memory. But I have to assign a specific identifier name to each word. Each word should be saved in the vocabulary like this: 'term_id'. I would imagine the content of my output file something like:

   house_1
   flower_2
   river_3.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
import csv
big_set_of_words = set()
with open("csvfile.csv") as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','newline='')
  for row in csv_reader:
    word_with_hash = (row[0], hash(row[0]))
    big_set_of_words.add(word_with_hash)

with open("outputfile.csv", mode = "w", newline='') as output_file:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
  for element in big_set_of_words:
    csv_writer.writerow(element)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I got this error generated from the "for" iteration:

        UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1088: character maps to <undefined>

Probably I have to change the encode mode in the csv.reader function into "utf-8" but. But there is no encode field expected for that function. Any idea?

Comment: You can try passing the encoding to the `open` function - `with open("csvfile.csv", encoding="utf8")`

Comment: Now it' giving me an error on the csv.writer():

       argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: I've corrected the error (my bad on renaming the output file). But the csv output file doesn't store words. This is the output content: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18AWOZismdq_N9Pxy16RGB9jbs-u3o3hY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Based on the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html I have edited the answer a little - let me know if this works

Comment: Now the error occurs when adding word_with_hash to the set. This is the error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. In python, lists are unhashable. But tuples can be hashed. So, we need to `word_with_hash` to be a tuple. See the edit

Comment: Still not there. I had to remove the newline=' ' field from the csv.reader function because it was not an allowed field. and now my output file looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rpsFWxu6ZEA7JFgeT-eR-2OaLrDT0hXm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of your csv file?

Comment: Sure! Here it is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R49vs4kRNPnkR-QOhq3btr9cR7_QHOzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see any words here? Which column are you trying to Extract?

Comment: There are words indeed. Well since the aim is to create a search engine I would like to include in my vocabulary at least all the words of the columns "description", "title", "city".